# WSO2 JUnit/Integration Testing

Tags: junit, wso2

I'm in the process of building a Carbon Archive using the new WSO2 Developer Studio.  I'm trying to work out how I can wrap the components (Sequences/Proxies etc) in JUnit tests.  These tests will need to run as part of a CI build process (Jenkins) in order to detect errors with any modified code.  I've done some research and can't seem to find anything that immediately stands out on how to achieve this. I did find this link https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-855
which suggests that it hasn't yet been implemented.  Can anyone confirm when this will be implemented or if there is any way at present to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no straight forward way to implement this scenario and this feature will be supported in a future version.

One mechanism i can think is that, add a separate Test module as a part of the build which executes after building C-Apps.

So what happens in here is that, first Jenkins produce the CAR  file for C-Apps. Then Maven start executing the JUnit test suite. Before the execution of Test Suite, you can configure maven to copy the CAR files to Servers and start up server. Then execute the Test Cases against the started up server.

This way you can deploy the new CAR files in your Carbon Server and execute the tests against the new configuration in the Server.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana